Error occurs when I attempt to run Parquet Datastream code?
I am attempting to run a Bulk Datastream using Parquet Data. Here is the code...
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path;
import org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.*;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.generated.ParquetData;
import org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.*;
import org.apache.flink.table.types.logical.*;
import  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.table.runtime.typeutils.InternalTypeInfo;

import java.time.Duration;
import org.apache.flink.table.data.*;

public class parquetIngest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path path = new Path("/home/vbundu/Assign1/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/examples/src/main/python/feed/");
        

        final LogicalType[] fieldTypes =
        new LogicalType[] {
                new DoubleType(), 
                new DoubleType(), new DoubleType(), new DoubleType(), new DoubleType()};

        final RowType rowType = RowType.of(fieldTypes, new String[] { "PULocationID", "DOLocationID",
            "Passenger_count", "Trip_distance", "Total_amount"});

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        final ParquetColumnarRowInputFormat<FileSourceSplit> format =
            new ParquetColumnarRowInputFormat<>(
                    conf,
                    rowType,
                    InternalTypeInfo.of(rowType),
                    15,
                    false,
                    true);

    
        final FileSource<RowData> source =
        FileSource.forBulkFileFormat(format, path)
                .build();

        // set up the batch execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        /*
         * Here, you can start creating your execution plan for Flink.
         *
         * Start with getting some data from the environment, like
         *  env.readTextFile(textPath);
         *
         * then, transform the resulting DataSet<String> using operations
         * like
         *  .filter()
         *  .flatMap()
         *  .join()
         *  .coGroup()
         *
         * and many more.
         * Have a look at the programming guide for the Java API:
         *
         * http://flink.apache.org/docs/latest/apis/batch/index.html
         *
         * and the examples
         *
         * http://flink.apache.org/docs/latest/apis/batch/examples.html
         *
         */

        
        //Setting up the stream 
        final DataStream<RowData> stream =
            env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "file-source");

        // execute program
        stream.print();
        env.execute("Flink Batch Java API Skeleton");
    }
}


However I come across this error when I run my jar file. I have been following the documentation for Parquet Datastream. The dependencies within the pom.xml is relatively recent as well

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected type: INT64
at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.vector.ParquetSplitReaderUtil.createWritableColumnVector(ParquetSplitReaderUtil.java:443)
~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createWritableVectors(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:284)
~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReaderBatch(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:273)
~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createPoolOfBatches(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:263)
~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReader(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:140)
~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.createReader(ParquetVectorizedInputFormat.java:76)
~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.checkSplitOrStartNext(FileSourceSplitReader.java:112)
~[flink-connector-files-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.connector.file.src.impl.FileSourceSplitReader.fetch(FileSourceSplitReader.java:65)
~[flink-connector-files-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.FetchTask.run(FetchTask.java:58)
~[flink-connector-files-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.runOnce(SplitFetcher.java:165)
~[flink-connector-files-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SplitFetcher.run(SplitFetcher.java:117)
~[flink-connector-files-1.18.0.jar:1.18.0]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
~[?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]

